# Do not want to cache the static files in Vert.x

Tags: vert.x

I am creating a simple webapp in Vert.x that will run on Docker, but I don't want Vert.x to cache any of static files as it might not have permissions on Docker to write files.

so as per documentation I am using

`-Dvertx.disableFileCaching=true`

then also it is creating .vertx folder and cached files.

If I use

`-Dvertx.disableFileCPResolving=true`

it is not creating .vertx folder but I am not able to access static files at all.

Any other settings i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files are inside the JAR and classpath resolving is disabled, then Vert.x will not be able to server them.

You should put your static files in a `webroot` directory under the JVM working directory.